# Django, reg ex for url dispatcher to capture foreign chars in string

Tags: django, django-urls

I have some legacy url paths to deal with - they take the form /path/عت چاپ، صفحه‌آرایی

Try as I might, I can't construct a reg ex to deal with them.  Have tried the following:

```
url(r'^path/(?P<title>[\w\+%_&!?,. ]+)/$', views.legacy_path),
```

Which I expected to pretty much cover it but it seems I'm missing something.  I don't read the strings so not really sure if they contain plenty of other chars but to be safe i suppose i need to include at least '?!,.-'

For one I haven't been able to add a '-' as I get a mal configued regular expression error, maybe that's the link, or maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way, could rtl be an issue here?